# Why does not "SHOW PROCESSLIST" give Host IP?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, network-programming

I execute "SHOW PROCESSLIST" on the client App.

it gives the Output:
[image]

When I look at Host column it displays in one of the row as "WIN-R2VUKMIS1PR:54822"

How do I get to know what the host IP is "WIN-R2VUKMIS1PR:54822"...

I am writing a c program that executes "SHOW PROCESSLIST"
and displays the output of all connected hosts.

So how do I resolve the Host name to IP? I tried using

Here is the demo app I used to convert "WIN-R2VUKMIS1PR:54822" to IP:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]) {
    struct hostent *h;

    /* error check the command line */
    if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s hostname\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* get the host info */
    if((h=gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
        herror("gethostbyname(): ");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Hostname: %s\n", h->h_name);
        printf("IP Address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)h->h_addr)));}

    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something? :-)

Comment: Just a sidenote, Take a look at your final `if`. I guess some `{}` are missing.

Comment: Thank you Muggen. I could not indent it properly. Thanks for your edit. Much Appreciated!

Comment: @Muggen: It is working fine. There is no problem with "if". When I run this program and pass google.com as parameter it will result in perfect IP.

Comment: @Muggen: Ok I got you.. :-) Yes set of {}'s are missing..

Comment: Just a side note: a server may have multiple IPs.  Even a single process may listen on multiple IPs (usually one internal, one external) and expose different services to each.

Answer (score 2):

You may use gethostbyname_r -- find network host database entry matching host name.
 But note it is deprecated. So careful if your app is going live.

Also, I am not sure whether it might help you.